# Using js.erb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 5 app with `devise`, I need to use a `new.js.erb` file to update select tag in my registrations view and controller. I cant seem to figure out why my `new.js.erb` file isn't working.

I've tried to use `respond_to` in controller as below,

**registrations-controller.rb**

```
 def new
   super 
   @cities = CS.get(:us,params[:state]) 
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render '/new.js.erb' }# layout: false }          
     format.html 
   end
 end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>
   <div class="signup-input-container">
     <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "firstname", placeholder: "First name", class: "signup-input-container--input" %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(CS.states(:us).map { |code, name| [name, code] }),{:prompt => "State"}, {:class => "signup-input-container--input", :id => "state-picker"} %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <%= f.select :city, options_for_select([]),{}, {:class => "signup-input-container--input", :id => "city-picker"} %> 
     </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
  var city = document.getElementById("city-picker");

  while (city.firstChild) city.removeChild(city.firstChild);

  var placeholder = document.createElement("option");
  placeholder.text = "Choose a city";
  placeholder.value = "";
  city.appendChild(placeholder);

 <% @cities.each do |c| %>
   city.options[city.options.length] = new Option('<%= c %>');
 <% end %>
```

**main.js**

```
  var state = document.getElementById("state-picker");
  state.addEventListener("change", function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/states?state=" + state.value,
        type: "GET"
     })
  })
```

I'm expecting this to create select tag options with my array of cities in my controller. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Check in the server logs - which controller and action are you calling with AJAX?

Comment: my log read "Processing by Families::RegistrationsController#new as */*"

Comment: thanks for the quick response btw @Vasilisa!

Comment: It's not a good idea - add 'get cities for selected state' functionality to default Devise controller. Result is unpredictable. Try to create new CitiesController, or maybe a new action `state_cities` in any existing suitable controller, add route to the action, move code and change url in ajax call to corresponding.

Comment: THANK YOU <3! I LOVE THIS COMMUNITY :D

Comment: Does that comment solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you should just setup a separate controller where you can fetch the data from asynchronously and alternatively there are also several free API's which can be used for geographical lookup such as [Googles Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1) and [Geonames](https://www.geonames.org/).

To setup a separate controller you can do it by:

```
# /config/routes.rb
get '/states/:state_id/cities', to: 'cities#index'

# /app/controllers/cities_controller.rb
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  # GET
  def index
    @cities = CS.get(:us, params[:state_id]) 
    respond_to do |f|
      f.json { render json: @cities }
    end
  end
end
```

I would skip using a `.js.erb` template altogether and just return JSON data which you can use directly in your JS or with one of the many existing autocomplete solutions. `.js.erb` only makes sense for extensive HTML templating (like for example rendering an entire form) where you want to reuse your server side templates - it greatly increases the complexity and generally makes a mess of your javascript which is not worth it just to output a list of option tags.

```
// If you are using jQuery you might as well setup a delegated
// handler that works with turbolinks, 
$(document).on('change', '#state-picker', function(){
  $.getJSON("/states/" + $(this).value() + "/cities", function(data){
    // using a fragment avoids updating the DOM for every iteration.
    var $frag = $('<select>');
    $.each(data, function(city){
      $frag.append('<option>' + data + '</option>');
    });
    $('#city-picker').empty()
                  .append($('frag').children('option'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Please note that this is a rough example of how the task can be accomplished - it is in no way a complete solution that you can copy-paste into your app.

Comment: Can someone actually answer the main question as I have the same issue and this didn't answer it.  I have multiple rails apps v6 that will not under ANY circumstance launch a javascript action file such as index.js.erb even if I only have js in the respond_to block

Comment: @ScottMilella this is the answer to the main question. You should not tack on a bunch of unrelated functionality to the devise controller and doing so would require you to understand how it uses the responders gem. It's not a valid option.